# Creating an Interface and a Concrete class and using them in a vector leads to a weird behavior when calling methods

Tags: c++, vector, abstract-class

I've been trying to implement an interface class (abstract class) in C++ and a few concrete classes based on it.

It seems to work quite well, until I put them in a vector of `shared_ptr<Interface>` and try to call the methods on the elements.

The methods without argument work as expected (i.e. the Concrete class methods is called), but for methods with an argument the Interface method is called instead.

It's probably easier to explain through code, so here is a minimal example that shows it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Interface{
  public:
    virtual ~Interface() = 0;
    virtual void foo(){
      std::cout << "Interface::foo" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void bar(std::shared_ptr< Interface >){
      std::cout << "Interface::bar" << std::endl;
    }
};
Interface::~Interface(){}

class Concrete: public Interface{
  public:
    virtual void foo(){
      std::cout << "Concrete::foo" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void bar(std::shared_ptr< Concrete >){
      std::cout << "Concrete::bar" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
  std::shared_ptr< Concrete > a = std::make_shared< Concrete >();
  a->foo();
  a->bar(a);
  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::vector< std::shared_ptr< Interface > > vec{};  
  vec.push_back( a );
  vec[0]->foo();
  vec[0]->bar(a);

  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Concrete::foo
Concrete::bar

Concrete::foo
Interface::bar
```

What am I doing wrong? Btw, the same happens even if I were to use an array with regular pointers

Comment: virtual void bar(std::shared_ptr< Concrete >) doesn't match the base class one  virtual void bar(std::shared_ptr< Interface >), modify the concrete one to use std::shared_ptr<Interface> instead

Comment: Yes, that works! :)

So there is not a way to have an implementation of Concrete::bar that only accepts a pointer to Concrete?

Am I thinking it the wrong way?

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi Why are you answering in the comments section? This is not a chatroom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

virtual void bar(std::shared_ptr< Concrete >)

Doesn't match the base class one.

virtual void bar(std::shared_ptr< Interface >)

In order to have the correct polymorphic behavior you need to modify the concrete one to have the same signature. Modify it to std::shared_ptr< Interface >. If you are using C++11 you can use the override keyword to make your intention explicit http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override. The compiler will notify the error to you if you are not overriding an existing virtual method.